# Could not make epub reader show up with Epub.js from futurepress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, epub.js

I am building a web app where I try to display a epub reader in the page using [Epub.js from futurepress](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js). However, I could not get the reader show up even with the example book link. Could anyone tell me where I did wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="viewers"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Read now</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/epubjs/dist/epub.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

[image]

Even the API request returns 200, nothing is happening on the webpage. (PS: For HTML, button is not originally there, I used jquery to render the button, but I don't think this is a problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an additional option to ePub function

```js
ePub("https://s3.amazonaws.com/moby-dick/moby-dick.epub", { openAs: "epub" })
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much! Even though last week I end up changing the design to have a workaround (open the epub in a new tab)

Comment: this is the current way, nice. here's the old way for google searchers: {contained: true} but this is no longer the case